# UBER Driver State Timeout (SANDBOX MODE)

Tags: uber-api

I was trying to change the state of the driver to accept a ride and it keeps on giving me a 500 internal server error saying that it was a ride dispatch timeout.

I did change the state from offline - online and it's working fine.

Any work arounds on this one ?

This is on sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's just me, I chose the wrong ID that produces this error. It's all working now.